# React wrapper to return child on <Route> component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is it possible in React to conditionally render a  inside a  using this kind of component?

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { useApplication } from 'ice-components'

const canEdit = (currentUser) => {
    if (currentUser.settings.canEditSpecRec.value === 'False' || !currentUser.location.isSpecimenReceptionType) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

const Permissions = ({ children }) => {
    const { currentUser } = useApplication()
    if (!canEdit(currentUser)) {
        return null
    }
    return children
}
Permissions.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
}
export { Permissions as default, canEdit }
```

And the route is made in this way:

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path component={component_1} />
   <Route path='/anotherPath' component={component_2} />
<Switch>
```

I tried to wrap the Permissions component around a single Route component but it breaks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to conditionally render a Route is the one provided by the section Auth of the react-router documentation:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

What's different in your application is that you're not authorizing based on authentication but on some user permission, you could do something like this:

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        canEdit(currentUser) ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/",
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Wrapping the Route in a PrivateRoute component that will return your route if user has permission to or something else if not (maybe a redirect).

```
export default function AuthExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>



        <Switch>
          <Route path="/public">
            <PublicPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage />
          </Route>
          <PrivateRoute path="/protected">
            <ProtectedPage />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```